# Optimize mysql query, on table with 32 million records

Tags: mysql

I have a database that I have created from DISCOG, currently it takes between 32 and 40 seconds to query the database for one record, my query looks similar to;

```
SELECT MIN(NULLIF(year, 0)) as year, genre, release_date, styles 
FROM track_master 
WHERE (artist LIKE '%Lo%Fidelity%Allstars%') 
  AND (track LIKE '%Battle Flag%')
```

`year`, `genre`, `release_date`, `styles`, `artist` and `track` are all indexed, when I ran the query with `EXPLAIN` I received a `ALL` under `TYPE` column, which as I've been reading is NOT good, however I do not know what else to do to optimize the query.

Besides the mentioned columns, there is also

```
id int(25)
release_id int(25)
album_title varchar(2250)
master_id int(25)
main_release int(5)
artist_id int(25)
```

Comment: Your WHERE conditions cause full table search (no index can be used to optimize them). So the only way to optimize this query may be `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON track_master (artist, track)` - it can replace table scan with index scan as a "compact table". *Besides the mentioned columns, there is also* You store both `artist` and `artist_id` in this table? Why `artist` (name?) is not stored in separate table? *int(25)* strange datatype - integer cannot store so much digits, 11 max (including negative sign)...

Comment: @Akina: `int(25)` is valid syntax for MySQL as can be verified with the following [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=adcd5c47800711da0781b6897fd8b681)

Comment: @hot2use Yes, it is valid... but it does not make sense.

Comment: artist_id is stored in this table, because there is also a table called artist_name_variations, just in case the tag has a different variation of the name.

Comment: after the search goes through all the files, the ones it did not find can be then searched using variations, if I did it at the same time each search was running about 2 1/2 minutes per song.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **full text** index to your table as

```
ALTER TABLE track_master
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `artist_key` (`artist`)
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `track_key` (`track`);
```

Also you need to tweak mysql server settings to support 2 character words. Find the mysql config file, In case of UBUNTU based server it is `/etc/my.cnf` and then locate the statement `innodb_ft_min_token_size=3` and change it to `innodb_ft_min_token_size=2`. Then restart mysql server.

After that rewrite your query and use it as

```
SELECT MIN(NULLIF(year, 0)) as year, genre, release_date, styles 
FROM track_master 
WHERE MATCH(artist) AGAINST ('Lo Fidelity Allstars')
AND MATCH(track) AGAINST ('"Battle Flag"')
```

Comment: `AGAINST ('Lo Fidelity Allstars')` - **Lo** token will be ignored with default full text settings (innodb_ft_min_token_size=3). And some records which do not match the author's request will be found.

Comment: You can always add the original criteria to the were clause given by Kapil.

Comment: @Akina I know this fact but this requires tweaking server settings, Do you this suggesting server settings at the same time is good idea?

Comment: I'd like to say that the task which is solved by your query slightly differs from the task the author is searching the answer for...